# plot groupwise time series in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a datset like below

[image]

I want to plot time series for each crop type and the plot should show all the 14 time-series using line and clour of lines should be unique for each group.
I tried to plot this after melting the data but it is not working.

my code

```
meltd = melt(mds,id.vars=c("crop"),value.name="value",
                     variable.name="Date" )
meltd = meltd %>% 
          mutate(across('Date', str_replace, '_', ' ')) %>% 
          mutate(Date = paste0("01 ", str_to_title(Date))) %>% 
          mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format= "%d %b %y"))


P<- meltd %>%
           ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=value, group = crop, colour = crop))+
            geom_line() +
            labs(y= "VV", x = "Date")
```

Output is like above example
[image]

As per my understanding ggplot is plotting one time-series for one crop type which I do not want.
Link for the sample data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-9R4boxzhzueu79MDyr0gfcPljWNGq40/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114652882170449489723&rtpof=true&sd=true

Kindly help me to resolve this isuue.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Just include your data directly via `dput()`.

Comment: This said: From the image of your data you have multiple rows of data per crop and hence multiple obs. per crop and date which results in vertical connecting lines. Hence you have to account of that, maybe by summarizing, e.g. computing the mean of duplicated crops?

Comment: You probably need to edit the “crop” column values so each row has a unique character value. That way you avoid having all the “rice” values with the same color and a single “line”.

Comment: Either a mean of each crop or, I think closer to what you asked, add a variable called "ID" or something unique to each row.  Plot "ID" against the yearly data, colour by crop?

Comment: Ok, let me try that... Ok I melted the df with (crop and id) and plotted as suggested by Paul and it worked... Thanks Paul... Please post it as answer so that I can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @stefan, there are multiple observations per day per group which causes the weird lines.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Crop, names_to = "date") %>%
  mutate(across(date, mdy)) %>%
  group_by(Crop, date) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value)) %>% # Mean of each date, per group
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = date, y = value, col = Crop) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t think he asked for summary within crop names. I think each row was supposed to be distinct.

Comment: yes... I can also summarise and plot it. I can also loop over the rows and add lines for each time-series using R base plot function, but I want to do it in gpplot.